# Can SAP detect encoding and line endings?

Tags: encoding, ftp, abap, line-endings

How to read ASCII files with mixed line endings (Windows and Unix) and UTF-16 Big Endian files in SAP?

Background: our ABAP application must read some of our configuration files. Most of them are ASCII files (normal text files) and one is Unicode Big Endian. So far, the files were read using ASCII mode and things were fine during our test.

However, the following happened at customers: the configuration files are located on a Linux terminal, so it has Unix Line Endings. People read the configuration files via FTP or similar and transport it to the Windows machine. On the Windows machine, they adapt some of the settings. Depending on the editor, our customers now have mixed line endings.

Those mixed line ending cause trouble when reading the file in ASCII mode in ABAP. The file is read up to the point where the line endings change plus a bit more but not the whole file.

I suggested reading the file in BINARY mode, remove all the CRs, then replace all the remaining LFs by CR LF. That worked fine - except for the UTF-16 BE file for which this approach results in a mess. So the whole thing was reverted.

I'm not an ABAP developer, I just have to test this. With my background in other programming languages I must assume there is a solution and I tend to decline a "CAN'T FIX" resolution of this bug.

Comment: you've already a mostly working solution for non UTF-16 BE files. Couldn't you read the file in binary, check for the UTF BOM at the beginning of the file? Once you know the encoding, you can treat the file accordingly.

Comment: IMHO this isn't worth a full answer, but - it is definitely possible for a capable ABAP developer. However, I don't know of any existing and reusable auto-detect-anything-that-might-come-my-way-including-EBCDIC class, so it's roll your own - again...

Comment: This is not an ABAP problem. This is not even a programming problem. Just ensure that your FTP servers are configured to automatically change the endings while transferring files in ASCII mode. Anyway this is exactly why the ASCII mode in FTP was developed for. On a well configured FTP server in Windows for example transferring text files from Unix client in ASCII mode should automatically change the LF to CRLF and the other way round.

Comment: This is a [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/403879/ftp-exe-does-not-convert-end-of-line-characters-while-transferring-to-freebsd-ft) I asked some time ago on ServerFault. It might be helpful. The server I was working with was on a FreeBSD system and it turned out the conversion was disabled by default.

Comment: @Jagger - Technically you're right, but there are circumstances where it's easier to fix it on the ABAP side than to beat the Operations team into fixing their infrastructure...

Comment: @vwegert - I do not agree. Why put the effort in a monster that will not cover each and every case anyway? From my point of view it is far more easier to do it without a programming effort. I do not know what kind of an organisation it is and what there culture is, but if they do not have the processes to follow the easiest path possible and to check something that should be working by default anyway, then what does it say about them? Solutions that has been already in place for years should be used instead of reinventing the wheel over and over again.

Comment: @Jagger I don't disagree, I've just been in similar situations where I was right but had to implement the workaround anyway - for instance, you can't alway walk up to a paying customer and tell them "You're too stupid to run your systems".

Comment: @vwegert I know the pain. In fact once I had a similar situation. Text files that were to be used for migration were transferred from a Windows system to Unix system without the conversion, because the FTP server was configured in that way that the endings were not converted. Asked the IT to change that, received an answer, no way to do that because... already existing workarounds might be broken. :] Of course the workarounds were unable to be followed, because there was no central info anywhere about them.

Comment: @Jagger: thanks for the FTP info. It seems relevant in two ways: customers might transfer via FTP in BINARY mode (probably without exactly knowing what they do) or transfer in ASCII mode with line encoding conversion or even transfer in ASCII mode without line ending conversion. As we're aware of the problem now, I have talked to the training team and they'll add that in the trainings. However, I'd still like to have it fixed in ABAP as well to reduce training efforts and support efforts.

Comment: @Thomas is your SAP application server running on a Unix or Windows operating system?

Comment: @Jagger: mine is running on Windows, but our customers could run something else. Do you think the proposed CR/LF fix worked only well because it's Windows? I'd have no chance to test that.

Comment: @Thomas I am asking because on Unix machines there is a command line tool `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` which changes the endings. I do not know how it behaves in case of UTF-16 BE files but I could assume it handles it without a problem. There is a way to call system tools from ABAP and it would be the easiest way. The prerequisite however is that SAP app server runs on Unix/Linux. I do not now any similar command line tool in Windows.

Comment: Can you post file sample?

Comment: @Suncatcher: ok. This will take some time. Internet access is restricted from my office. I'll post it when I'm back home

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CL_ABAP_FILE_UTILITIES=>CHECK_FOR_BOM`to determine which encoding the file has and then use the constants of class `CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES` to process further.